# Dart is looking in the application directory for packages (Failed to load resource)

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

I'm getting an error running the WebUI new project generated code:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    http://127.0.0.1:3030/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/pkg/web_ui/web_ui.dart
Failed to load a file http://127.0.0.1:3030/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/pkg/web_ui/web_ui.dart
```

I've run the `pub install`, and the packages are symlinked from the project/packages directory.

Is there a flag I should be setting?

pub.yaml:

```
name: test
description: A sample WebUI application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  js: any
  web_ui: any
```

Comment: Is this from a brand new project generated by Dart Editor? Can you list the steps you took which lead to the error?

Comment: Also, can you paste in your pubspec.yaml? I suspect you have a bug in there, because web_ui is not a pkg package.

Comment: Running build 18300 on OSX.  I created a new web application using the web_ui library.  Right click on the project html file (ie test.html), `Run in Dartium`. `out/` contains `test.dart`, `test.html`, `test.html_bootstrap.dart`, and `xclickcounter.dart`.  Pasted the `pub.yaml` above.

Comment: I just tried it, same editor version. Created sample app with sample content. I ran out/test.html and it worked. Is your project available to see, e.g. on Github? Can you try to create a new temp project?

Comment: Also, try deleting the packages/ directory and see if it gets recreated.

Comment: Deleted `packages/`, it got recreated, but got the same error. pushed to https://github.com/chambery/test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the Package-root directory in the Preferences > Editor, Directory Settings pointing to `/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/pkg/`.  Clearing out this field corrected the problem.

Comment: This setting was left over from a previous installation (though I can't remember why I set it in the first place :-P).

Comment: But this sets package-root directory for all projects to `/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/pkg/` but in my case each project has it's specific dependencies.

Comment: Have thesame error, but I do not have a "Directory Settings" field in Preferences->Editor. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happen also when you copy/paste or move folders. To fix it you may try to open pubspec.yaml and click on "Run Pub install" (Pub Actions). This works fine for me in some cases.